# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException occurs while updating the datatable from the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, gridview, datatable

I'm updating the row in a grid view as well as the DataTable using the Rowcommand event but an exception occurs while assigning the values to the row in the  DataTable.

```
 protected void grduser_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Update")
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dtable"];

            Int32 index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            GridViewRow row = grduser.Rows[index];
           // after this statement the exception occurs!
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["userid"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[0].Controls[0])).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["username"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].FindControl("txtuname"))).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["usertype"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["email"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["salary"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[4].FindControl("txtsalary"))).Text;
            grduser.EditIndex = -1; 
            ViewState["dtable"]=dt;
            grduser.DataSource = (DataTable)(ViewState["dtable"]);
            grduser.DataBind();

        }

    }
```

// The grid view source below.

```
       <asp:GridView ID="grduser" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        onrowediting="grduser_RowEditing"   onrowupdating="grduser_updateRow"
         >

<Columns>
<asp:BoundField   HeaderText="Id" DataField="userid"/>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtuname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("username") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("username") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="User Type" DataField="usertype" />
 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Email" DataField="email" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Salary">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtsalary" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("salary") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("salary") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: the line exactly below the commented line

Comment: may be here `GridViewRow row = grduser.Rows[index]`

Comment: No it happens in the next line

Comment: check this `((TextBox)(row.Cells[0].Controls[0])).Text` is it giving some thing or not ?
`row.DataItemIndex` this also, what it is givng?

Comment: @yogi Yes there's some problem with this statement: ** bold ((TextBox)(row.Cells[0].Controls[0])).Text**, it's throwing the exception . it was working when i checked it earlier in the Row_updating but now when i used it int the Row_command

Comment: @psylogic so now this the your problem. what exception message?

Comment: argument out of range exception

Comment: @psylogic post your gridview source code also..

Comment: @psylogic yes you source code for grdUser so that i can show youi how to access cell in code

Comment: @yogi Yes that will be very helpful because this is the first time i'me working on grid view. **please check the edit i've added the grduser source code to it**

Comment: Specify the control name in your RowCommand, don't use `Control[0]` eliminate also the `cell[0]`
Example: `((TextBox)(row.FindControl("txtbx1"))).Text;`

Could you post the CommandArgument in your gridview, this should be look like `CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"`

Comment: @Chris the bound fields dont have Ids so what should I pass in the **FindControl("?")**

Comment: IMHO, change the bound fields to template field and specify an ID to it.

Comment: You see that's the thing i can't change it to a template field I mean I don't have a choice. Is there any way i could keep it a bound field and still get the Text out of it?

Comment: Use `row.Cells[0].Text` instead.
Your userId is a boundfield right? don't cast it as TextBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this.

```
protected void grduser_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Update")
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dtable"];

            Int32 index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            GridViewRow row = grduser.Rows[index];

            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["userid"] = row.Cells[0].Text;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["username"] = ((TextBox)(row.FindControl("txtuname"))).Text;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["usertype"] = row.Cells[2].Text;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["email"] = row.Cells[3].Text;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["salary"] = ((TextBox)(row.FindControl("txtsalary"))).Text;
            grduser.EditIndex = -1; 
            ViewState["dtable"]=dt;
            grduser.DataSource = (DataTable)(ViewState["dtable"]);
            grduser.DataBind();

        }

    }
```

Comment: NOPE NOT WORKING FOR THE BOUND FIELDS!

Comment: Have your tried to debug it? I have tried several times on my machine and it works. Are you sure Its not working?

Comment: @Chris OP was getting System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException - it's in the question title.

Comment: He already tagged my answer as answered and he retract it back.

Comment: @Chris it's not giving an error but the values in the bound field don't get updated but it worked when i did it like this: dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["userid"]=((TextBox)(row.Cells[0].Controls[0])).Text;

Comment: I assumed you just only have a button to update the fields. You used the Edit, Cancel and Update functionality of the gridview.
Your code will work because the template is set to Edit mode.

I usually used templated grid, instead of the bound field. I usually used boundfield when only retrieving data with out editing the values on it.

Comment: @Chris I would do the same but, in this case I had to make it (whatever i was given) work. Thank you Chris! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because your `e.CommandArgument` is not a valid row number from your `GridView`. For instance, your `grduser` has 3 rows and your `e.CommandArgument` is set to 3. This will throw a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because the `grduser.Rows` is 0-based and you are most likely setting it starting with 1.

Comment: not actually setting it by choice, I'm fetching the index of that particular row directly on the click of the update.

Comment: @psylogic I understand you are fetching it on click. I'm saying it was previously being set improperly on the initial bind, back when you were using e.CommandArgument.

Comment: So how can we solve that issue? because as far as i know the row is triggering the event so the index should be of that row. Do enlighten me on this one as I am more than willing to know better though I did solve the issue a little differently.

Comment: @psylogic There is too much missing information for an accurate elaboration. You have solved your issue, but by changing the code as opposed to fixing the issue. Either way works. :)